# Density of $XY$, where $X,Y$~$Unif(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X,Y$ be two independent random variables uniformly distributed in $(0, 1)$.

> Compute the density of $W := XY$. Hint: First compute the joint density of $(X, XY )$

We have the following denisties: $f_X(x)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$, $f_Y(y)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(y) \Rightarrow f_{X,Y}=\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(y)$

Following the hint, let $W=XY$ and $V=X$, then I define $g(x,y)=(x,xy)=(v,w)\Rightarrow g^{-1}(v,w)=(v,\frac{w}v)$. Then the Jacobian is: $J_{g^{-1}}(v,w)=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\-\frac{w}{v^2}&\frac1v \end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow \left|\det{J_{g^{-1}}(v,w)} \right|=\frac1{\left|v\right|} $. Hence we have $f_{V,W}=f_{X,Y}(v,\frac{w}v)\frac1{\left|v\right|}\mathbb{1}_{V\not=0}$.
Then the marginal should be $f_{XY}(xy)=f_W(w)=\int f_{X,Y}(v,\frac{w}v)\frac1{\left|v\right|}dv=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)\frac1{\left|x\right|} dx=\int^1_0\frac1{\left|x\right|}dx=\infty$

I don't think this is the right answer, but I don't know what I am missing, can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that $v = x, w = xy$ and $0 \leq x, y \leq 1$.

So, $w \leq v \leq 1$

Marginal density of $W, f_W(w) =  \displaystyle \int_w^1 \frac1{\left|v\right|} \ dv = - \ln w$

Answer (score 2):

You must pay attention to the support indication.

$$\begin{aligned}f_{\small X,XY}(x,w) &=\begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial\langle x,w/x\rangle}{\partial\langle x,w\rangle}\end{Vmatrix}\cdot f_{\small X,Y}(x,w/x)\\[1ex]&=\lvert x^{-1}\rvert\cdot\mathbf 1_{\small(0,1)}(x)\,\mathbf 1_{\small(0,1)}(w/x)&:~&0<x<1 ~\&~ 0<w/x<1\\[1ex]&=x^{-1}\,\mathbf 1_{(0,1)}(w)\,\mathbf 1_{(w,1)}(x)&:~&0<w<x<1\\[2ex] f_{\small XY}(w) &=\int_w^1 x^{-1}\,\mathbf 1_{\small(0,1)}(w)\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&= -\ln (w)\,\mathbf 1_{\small(0,1)}(w)\end{aligned}$$